# Why's the Graph of $y = \sin (\cos (e^x))$ so Wonky?

Tags: graphing-functions

I was recently messing around with desmos by plotting random graphs.
I came across this peculiar function, namely $y = \sin (\cos (e^x))$.
I noticed that the graph is basically a sine wave whose period gets shorter and shorter. However, at a few $x$ values, this trend falters for a bit.
[[image: The points I'm referring to are near <span class=]$x = 8$, where there are white specks instead of the expected red.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJhvu.jpg)

The points I'm referring to are near $x = 8,$ where there are white specks instead of the expected red. Can someone give me an insight into why this may be happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you also tried plotting the thing you are plugging into $\sin$ (i.e. plotting $y=\cos\left(e^x\right)$)?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth How is that supposed to help? It's a function that oscillates faster and faster between $-1$ and $1$, just like this one should oscillate faster and faster between $-\sin1$ and $\sin1$.

Comment: Maybe by visualising what you're plugging in to sine, you could better visualise the output. Anyway, doesn't hurt to try when exploring this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The software may be performing some sampling on $x$ values to plot your function.

When the frequency of your function is low, for this case when $x$ is small, the effect of sampling is not noticeable.

But when the frequency of your function is too high relative to the sampling frequency, precisely when your function's frequency is higher than [half the sampling frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) occurs and your function is replaced by a lower-frequency function that has the same sample values.

In the extreme case, when the frequency of your function is around a multiple of the sampling frequency, the alias from the samples can appear to be a constant function, a function with lower frequency.

This may give the effect of the missing red around $x=8$, when the displayed frequency of the function is lower than expected.

Answer (score 8):

That’s simply a rendering error with the software. The graph continues to oscillate as you’d expect. Zoom in and the problem should resolve itself.